# Joining 2 Tables on Multiple Non Foreign Key Columns in Flask with SQLAlchemy and Retrieving All Columns

Tags: sqlalchemy, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a few tables shown below that I would like to join on columns that are not foreign keys to each other's tables and then have access to the columns of both. Here are the classes:

```
class Yi(db.Model):

    year = db.Column(db.Integer(4), primary_key=True)
    industry_id = db.Column(db.String(5), primary_key=True)
    wage = db.Column(db.Float())
    complexity = db.Column(db.Float())

class Ygi(db.Model, AutoSerialize):

    year = db.Column(db.Integer(4), primary_key=True)
    geo_id = db.Column(db.String(8), primary_key=True)
    industry_id = db.Column(db.String(5), primary_key=True)
    wage = db.Column(db.Float())
```

So, what I would like to get are the columns of both tables joined by the IDs I specify, in this case Year and industry_id. Is this possible? Here is the SQL I've written to achieve this...

```
SELECT 
    yi.complexity, ygi.* 
FROM
    yi, ygi 
WHERE 
    yi.year = ygi.year and 
    yi.industry_id = ygi.industry_id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One dirty way is :

```
q=session.query(Ygi,Yi.complexity).\
          filter(Yi.year==Ygi.year).\
          filter(Yi.industry_id==Ygi.industry_id)
```

Which gives you :

```
SELECT ygi.year AS ygi_year, ygi.geo_id AS ygi_geo_id, 
       ygi.industry_id AS ygi_industry_id, ygi.wage AS ygi_wage,
       yi.complexity AS yi_complexity 
FROM ygi, yi 
WHERE yi.year = ygi.year 
AND yi.industry_id = ygi.industry_id
```

I find this *dirty* because it does not use the **join() method**.
You can figure out how to use the **join()** with [the SQLAlchemy documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/orm/query.html?highlight=join#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.joinhttp://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/orm/query.html?highlight=join#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.join)

Then, you can choose to use a *virtual* model : see answer of **TokenMacGuy** in this question [Mapping a 'fake' object in SQLAlchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5637451/mapping-a-fake-object-in-sqlalchemy).
It will be a good solution.

Or you will just have a *YiYgi class* that will not be a sqlalchemy.Base derived class but just an object. It more a "hand-fashion" way to do it.

The class will have a classmethod get() method that will:

1. call the query you build just before,
2. call the **init** with the returned request lines and build up one instance per line

This is an example :

```
class YiYgi(object):

    def __init__(self,year, geo_id, industry_id, wage, complexity):
        # Initialize all your fields
        self.year = year
        self.geo_id = geo_id
        self.industry_id = industry_id
        self.wage = wage + 100  # You can even make some modifications to the values     here
        self.complexity = complexity

    @classmethod
    def get_by_year_and_industry(cls, year, industry_id):
        """ Return a list of YiYgi instances, void list if nothing available """
        q = session.query(Ygi,Yi.complexity).\
                    filter(Yi.year==Ygi.year).\
                    filter(Yi.industry_id==Ygi.industry_id)

        results = q.all()

        yiygi_list = []
        for result in results:
            # result is a tuple with (YGi instance, Yi.complexity value)
            ygi_result = result[0]
            yiygi = YiYgi(ygi_result.ygi_year, 
                          ygi_result.geo_id,
                          ygi_result.industry_id,
                          ygi_result.wage,
                          result[1])

            yiygi_list.append(yiygi)

        return yiygi_list
```